# What is these data structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have a javascript file with this variable. I don't understand what is the data structure. From what I read from W3Schools `var x = []` is used to create an array. So what is stored in the array?

```
var username = $("#username").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var role = "user";

var user = [
  {
    username: username
  },
  {
    email: email
  },
  {
    password: password
  },
  {
    role: role
  }
];
```

Comment: ‘user’ is an array containing four objects.

Comment: [JavaScript data types and data structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Answer (score 2):

It's an *array of objects*:

The *array* is designated by the square brackets `[]`.
Inside it you have a list of *objects* (designated by the curly brackets with `property:value` pairs inside them).

```
var user = [ //marks the start of the array
       { //marks the start of the object
            username: username //property:value pair
       },
       ...
    ]//marks the end of the array
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it is an array.

Rather than a data structure, you can call it an array which holds objects as its elements.

```
     {username : username}
```

Look at the first element of the array. This is an object which has the property "username" in the  left side. In the right side is the value of the property - which should be the current value of the variable named  "username" -

This variable is defined in the first line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple object array.

Also use MDN instead of W3Schools: [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Also note that in ES6 you can store object simpler when the key has the same name as the variable

```js
const username = "Fred";
const email = "a@b.com";
const password = "****";
const role = "user";

const user = [
  { username },
  { email    },
  { password },
  { role     }
];

console.log(user[1]); // email
console.log(user);
```

I suggest you use an object instead of an array

```js
const username = "Fred";
const email = "a@b.com";
const password = "****";
const role = "user";

const user = {
  username,
  email,
  password,
  role
};

console.log(user.email); // much easier
console.log(user);
```